# set a maximum time on execution of PL/SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle, testing, plsql

I am trying to do some performance load testing on some tables in our DB. The method we are using is basically a script that loops insert statements.  However, we want to know how many inserts a minute the system can handle. Currently, my scripts looks like such:

```
set serveroutput on
variable n number
exec :n := dbms_utility.get_time
begin 
for i in 1..5000 loop
insert into aoms.buyers (user_id,buyer_cd,buyer_eng_nm,reg_dt)
values(dbms_random.string('L',8),'LT0','LT04','LT05');
end loop;
end;
/
exec :n := (dbms_utility.get_time - :n)/100
exec dbms_output.put_line(:n)
```

Instead of just having a timer on the script I would like to insert as many records in 60 seconds as possible. How can this be done? Additionally, If I wanted to make this script more dynamic in nature and be able to use it on different tables with different structures (column names, primary keys) how would I go about that. Is it possible? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would run for 60 seconds:

```
set serveroutput on
variable n number
exec :n := dbms_utility.get_time + (6 * 100);
declare 
  l_cnt NUMBER := 0;
begin 
loop
insert into aoms.buyers (user_id,buyer_cd,buyer_eng_nm,reg_dt)
values(dbms_random.string('L',8),'LT0','LT04','LT05');
l_cnt := l_cnt + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
exit when dbms_utility.get_time > :n;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line('Rows inserted: ' || l_cnt);
end;
/
```

You need to make sure that it's a fair test though.  For example, `DBMS_RANDOM.STRING()` takes time.  Calling `DBMS_UTILITY` takes time.  You might want to couple this with `DBMS_HPROF` to find out exactly how much time is spent on the insert.

On the other side of the equation, your production system probably does a lot more than just insert.

As far as making things more generic, just replace `INSERT INTO AOMS.BUYERS...` with whatever test you're running.  I wouldn't make it any more generic than that.  For example, suppose you replaced the insert with a function call that accepted "table_name" as a parameter and then went and looked up the columns, the datatype of each, and figured out good test data for each column.  All that work (in my opinion) might skew your test results.

Comment: Thank you so much Matthew, this is exactly what I was looking for. Another question for you. Instead of a stand alone select statement. How would I output how many rows were inserted? maybe a dbms output?

Comment: I updated my answer to output the number of rows inserted

Comment: There is no commit :P